# Story about a driver whose car breaks down while taking a shortcut. He later realizes that the person who helped him was the Devil

Tags: story-identification

This story is about the traveler who takes a shortcut to save time but gets into trouble since his car breaks down. There is a solitary inn/motel/hotel. The owner extends him all the help. The mechanic arrives and sets his car. When the traveler is leaving, he realizes that the owner is a friendly devil.

Comment: Anthology One hundred great science fiction short short stories.
EDITED BY ISAAC ASIMOV, MARTIN HARRY GREENBERG AND JOSEPH D. OLANDER
Trace by Jerome Bixby

Comment: Thanks everyone 
I located the details of the story.

Comment: Does the Devil have an ulterior motive or is he sometimes inexplicably a good guy? That is not impossible. Like if he does not see a soul available, he is as nice as anyone else?

Comment: @mspd2003    There is a big difference between the title, mentioning The Devil, and the body of the question mentioned a devil.

Answer (score 4):

The story is [Trace](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62743) by Jerome Bixby. I read it in the anthology [100 Great Science Fiction Short Short Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?43) edited by Isaac Asimov, Martin Harry Greenberg and Joseph D. Olander.